# how to put ajax result to dynamically added container?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

could anyone help me with my ajax and jquery, my ajax is here:

```
function dropdown(elem){

            var typeid = $('#type').val();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url("admin/ajaxGetType"); ?>',
                /* post form field's value */
                { 'provid':typeid,},

                /* web server responds to the request */
                function(result) {$(this).closest('#sortable').children('#div_replace').html(result);   
                    console.log($(this).closest('#sortable'));

                },

                "html"

            );
}
```

my html is here

```
<div class="contain" id="sortable">
                <select class="form-control" id="type" onchange="dropdown(this)">
                    <option value="0">Choose Type</option>
                    <option value="1">form 1</option>
                    <option value="2">form 2</option>
                    <option value="3">form 3</option>
                    <option value="4">form 4</option>
                    <option value="5">form 5</option>
                </select>

                <span id="div_replace">
            </span>

         </div>
    <div class="contain" id="sortable">
                <select class="form-control" id="type" onchange="dropdown(this)">
                    <option value="0">Choose Type</option>
                    <option value="1">form 1</option>
                    <option value="2">form 2</option>
                    <option value="3">form 3</option>
                    <option value="4">form 4</option>
                    <option value="5">form 5</option>
                </select>

                <span id="div_replace">
            </span>

         </div>
```

my html is dynamic add like this one [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRyVp/565/) but its nothing to do with this fiddle.

What I am doing right is

-> onchange select 
 -> trigger function 
 -> getparent 
 -> get its child where `id = div_replace` 
 -> then put html result

but that's not working.

could anyone help me with this, please!

same approach or better one is fine,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As ids are unique I would take a simpler way to select and update an element

```
$.post( "<?php echo base_url("admin/ajaxGetType"); ?>", function( result) {
  $("#div_replace").html (result);
});
```

Comment: yeah that would do, but I don't know how to get id of div_replace( assuming this is unique) by just using select onchange

Comment: If it is not unique then it is not valid HTML. `$("#div_replace").html ("Hello");`  will replace the html content of the `div` having the id `div_replace` with the text `Hello`

Comment: oh that's why I'm getting error invalid html when I check the console. I'm not used to jquery or javascript so. but if it is unique how can i get it by using my trigger select

Comment: Change your `id` to `class` and you may just find it works.  Also is`elem == $(this)` ?

Comment: I see, i don't know i just tried the code, in my thought `this` is equal to `this instance`

Comment: But what is `this instance` now that you are in the result handler of an asynchronous ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Use the append event

```
function dropdown(elem){

            var typeid = $('#type').val();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url("admin/ajaxGetType"); ?>',
                /* post form field's value */
                { 'provid':typeid,},

                /* web server responds to the request */
                function(result) {
                    $("#div_replace").append(result);    
                },

                "html"

            );
}
```

Comment: i have tried it already yeah it put the result to the #div_replace but when i generate couple of more elements with the same id of div_replace appending the result wont work

Comment: In a DOM there can not be elements with same ID. You should give them different ID's or You can give a common class to all the dynamically generated div and then use append instead of the Html.See my answer again i am editing it.

Answer (score 0):

See as a valid markup in your page you have to use unique IDs for each element, so in your current markup you have duplicacy of same ids multiple times.

To overcome this kind of issue you can change your ids to class names and better to use javascript unobtrusive way:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="contain sortable">  //<---changed id to class here
   <select class="form-control type">//<---changed id to class here
      <option value="0">Choose Type</option>
      <option value="1">form 1</option>
      <option value="2">form 2</option>
      <option value="3">form 3</option>
      <option value="4">form 4</option>
      <option value="5">form 5</option>
   </select>
   <span class="div_replace"></span> //<---changed id to class here
</div>
```

#### JQuery:

```
function dropdown(typeval) {  //<----get the value here
    $.post('<?php echo base_url("admin/ajaxGetType"); ?>', {
        'provid': typeval //<---pass it here
    },
    function (result) {
        $(this).closest('.sortable').find('.div_replace').html(result);
        console.log($(this).closest('.sortable'));
    }, "html");
}

// and call it in here

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.sortable').on('change', '.type', function(){
        dropdown(this.value);  //<----pass the value here
   });
});
```

Comment: I have tried to change it to class `$(this).closest('.sortable').find('.div_replace').html(result);` but nothing happens and no error. But this give me idea that if i'm getting the container of dynamically added elements I must be working on class not id if id's not unique?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function dropdown(elem){
    var typeid = $('#type').val();
    var div_replace = $(elem).closest('#sortable').children('#div_replace');
    // var div_replace = $(elem).next(); another selector
    $.post('<?php echo base_url("admin/ajaxGetType"); ?>',
        /* post form field's value */
        { 'provid':typeid,},

        /* web server responds to the request */
        function(result) {
            div_replace.html(result);
        },
    );
}
```

selector you can use

```
var div_replace = $(elem).closest('#sortable').children('#div_replace');
var div_replace = $(elem).closest('#sortable').find('#div_replace');
var div_replace = $(elem).parent().find('#div_replace');
var div_replace = $(elem).next();
```

Comment: the selector 1&2 works fine for the first div but when I add couple of div's the div_replace content not changing.
the next 2&3 not working in my case